# Expression to replace characters in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, replace, regular-expression

I have a string field. Which requests to put the letter `F` after the number to all positive digits, and the letter `B` after minus digits and to delete the sign `-`.

Finally, I want a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array( LineCodes, ',' ),
        if(
            left( @element, 1 ) = '-',
            substr( @element, 2 ) + 'B',
            @element + 'F'
            )
        )
    )
```

[`string_to_array`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#string-to-array) : splits string into an array using comma
[`array_foreach`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-foreach) : runs given expression for every element in array
[`array_to_string`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-to-string) : concatenates elements into a string separated by comma

Comment: How do I rewrite this expression for the opposite
process? From 8F_16B_17B to 8,-16,-17

Comment: You'd better use a regular expression for this. I don't have enough experience on regular expressions. You can [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) this as another question.

Answer (score 10):

You can define your own custom expression function in Python and then use it in the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator).

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False)
def custom(input, feature, parent):
    if input is None:
        return None
    numbers = [int(num) for num in input.split(',')]
    def f(num):
        if num > 0:
            return '{}F'.format(num)
        return '{}B'.format(abs(num))
    result = map(f, numbers)
    return ','.join(result)
```

1. Define it by running the code above as a script in the [Python Console](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html#console):

   [image]
2. Use it in the Field Calculator:

   [image]

Answer (score 9):

You may also try the following expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array("test"),
        if(
            to_int(@element)>0,
            @element||'F',
            abs(@element)||'B'
            )
        )
    )
```

See, for example below

[image: result]

*P.S.* IMHO using the [`regexp_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) is pointless because more changes have to be applied rather than substitutions.